# Worksheet copying dynamic cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm hoping to get some idea on automating copying some data in-between columns and worksheets.

I have to clear column C, then copy B over, clear B then repeat for A. Where it gets tricky for me is that after this process data is generated in column D, which needs to be copied until the first cell in A is blank.

E.g. column A has data until row 200 then column D will generate information, I need to copy D2:D200 based off of what has been put in A

So to copy from D2 all the way down until A? is blank, how can i make the first range below variable?

```
Sheets("Calc").Select
Range("C214").Select
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=22
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-22
Sheets("Calc").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D2:D238").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=22
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Range("K2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You have just cleared column `A`. What does *until the first cell in A is blank -1* mean?

Comment: I'll edit the question, forget to mention that I copy in data from another sheet to replace column A.  As an example though, if column A has data until row 200 then column D will generate information due to a formula but it does so till the end of excel - so I need to copy D2:D200

Comment: `Destination worksheet` is the last sheet in the workbook. `Source worksheet` is not defined. Don't they have names (in the tabs)? Your code 'mentions' `K2`. Is that the starting cell where to copy the data in the `Destination worksheet`? Are you 'measuring' the size (rows) of the range according to values in column `A` of `Source` or `Destination worksheet`?

Comment: Pasted the whole thing in, was created by recording  a macro - hope it clears things up. The calc is always the first worksheet in the book and the active worksheet that's copied from/to after clearing the columns is always the last but that name changes everyday and the Range("D2:D238").Select needs to be based off of when A ends in calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Last Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updateLast()
    
    ' Constants
    Const srcFirst As String = "A2"
    Const srcCols As Long = 2
    Const dstFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dstResult As String = "K2"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Source
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets("Calc")
    Dim sRng As Range
    With src.Range(srcFirst)
        Set sRng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, srcCols)
        Set sRng = sRng.Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If sRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No source data found.", vbCritical, "No Data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set sRng = .Resize(sRng.Row - .Row + 1, srcCols)
    End With
    sRng.Copy sRng.Offset(, 1)
    sRng.Columns(1).ClearContents
    Set sRng = sRng.Cells(1)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dst As Worksheet: Set dst = wb.Worksheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Dim dRng As Range
    With dst.Range(dstFirst)
        Set dRng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        Set dRng = dRng.Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If dRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No destination data found.", vbCritical, "No Data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set dRng = .Resize(dRng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Copy
    dRng.Copy sRng
    With dst.Range(dstResult).Resize(dRng.Rows.Count)
        .Value = sRng.Offset(, srcCols + 1).Resize(dRng.Rows.Count).Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```